# How to write and testing ASP.NET 4 on notepad?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, notepad

Conditions:

1. I've been asked to develop a simple ASP.NET 4(C#) project **in notepad**. I'm completely new to this area.
2. The completed project should include **several .aspx files**, **one master page**, **one sitemap** and **a web.config**.
3. The book I'm using is a beginner cook book, based on using Visual Studio 2010 Express.
4. Developing it on notepad is a requirement to this school assignment.
   Questions:
5. As what I know now VS2010 has its built-in Development Web Server which notepad doesn't. Should I test .aspx files by opening notepad files in browser? Will tags with runat="server" work?
6. Is there any helpful site or post that you know?
7. How should I testing master page?

Forgive my noob questions. The most sites I can find is teaching people how to develop by using VS2010, which is like my book, instead of notepad. The schedule is tight so I need some help here. Thank you for your time. I'll also share my experience when I finish this assignment.

Comment: You should host your site in IIS. Create a site and map it to a directory, then save all your files in that directory. A question from me; **why** do you need to use notepad for this? Is it an interview assignment?

Comment: Exactly, why do you have to use notepad? VS, even the express versions allow you to build, test, publish you web apps. An ASP.NET app has to be hosted in IIS anyway.

Comment: It is an school assignment. It is an elective course for me. The things I learned before are java, sql, html and basic javascript. ASP.NET and C# are new stuff for me.I thought I want a challenging elective, so here I am:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little more complicated than "runat="server"".

To give a little bit of 101, you will need:

1. A web server. The most natural one to use is IIS. I believe you should be able to use Apache as well if you're feeling adventurous.
2. The application framework. Guess what, it's .NET! There's also Mono if you're not using IIS. The application framework should also include the compiler. C# is a compiled language, so before you can run the code, you will have to compile it first. This is slightly different when compared to PHP.
3. The editor. You should be able to use Notepad, but Visual Studio provides you with more than just a fancy text editor. It helps you create the build script (the command that you send to the compiler), it helps you with project organization, and it helps you debugging.

So just using Notepad is doable, but you'll lose so much time for not using a free tool like Visual Studio Express.

**Now to actually answer your questions:**

1. No, it doesn't work that way. You will need a web server (see point 1 above) and a compiler (see point 2 above).
2. That's a little bit too broad. Your book should be a good starting point.
3. See answer 1.

Comment: It seems to be more complicated than I expect. Developing it on notepad is a requirement to the assignment. I'll try to develop it on VS2010 and make it unnoticeable, because the deadline is so close. Thanks for answering my question:)

Comment: You may be able to use inline code inside the .aspx files to avoid the manual compilation step, but you will still need a web server. Microsoft Web Platform Installer comes to mind if you need to set one up easily http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have finished that assignment. Here is my experience:

First, to develop an ASP.NET project on notepad or textpad is very unwise, unless you want to test your coding skill or having some other reasons. Because for beginner the best way to test your code is using VS "Ctrl+F5". If you write your code in notepad/textpad and test them in VS, it kind of defeat the original purpose.

There is a few tips, for the beginner like me.

1. Named your sitemap file "**web.sitemap**", and put it in the **root directory** of your project, otherwise you may have to go through complicated configuration process.

P.S. This is not a compulsory requirement, you can change the file name or directory, but you need to add site map provider in "web.config".

2 Choose your solution or project root directory carefully, because it is not easy to redefine it.

P.S. I spent a lot of time to move files around in Windows Explorer because I wanted to change my current solution directory to another folder.

These are the tips I find most useful. I would've saved at least 2 hours if I know these in the beginning.